# Why aren't there more native command line shells for Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, shell

To my knowledge, the only native command-line shells out there for Windows are:

- Command Prompt
- PowerShell

I know there are others like Git Bash and Bash with Cygwin, but those require tools like Cygwin, MinGW or WSL to function and besides - they modify the root directory to have the Linux file structure and then "mount" the Windows drive. Are there any other *native* command-line shells for Windows? If not, why not?

Comment: Why are you looking for other command-line shells on Windows?  Isn't 2 enough?  On Linux they have csh, sh, bash, zsh, ksh and the scripts are not interchangeable.  If you get a script with no indication of which shell it is written for, it may or may not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there aren't any other Native shells because windows is closed source, and they never felt the need to create other shells. Thank goodness that you live in the post power-shell world, because 10 years ago powershell was just getting started and wasn't nearly so functional. before then we just had to use the VDM (cmd).

Most of the *nix shells out there are peoples graduate projects (the same reason that languages like [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_%28programming_language%29) and [BrainF%^$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) exist). also note that *nix has existed since the late '60s and lots of very idiosyncratic developers have implemented them over the years.

There are some script interpreters shipped with windows like [WSH/CSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host), but they are not actually free-standing shells, they just run in CMD or PS.

Comment: MS-DOS isnt a shell, its an operating that contains the command shell (command.com)

Comment: One could argue that WSL **IS** native since it has access to your Windows files. So literally anything that’s possible with bash is now possible on Windows

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like by Native, you actually don't mean native, but you mean, not necessarily coming from Microsoft,  you mean not Linux based.

There was something called 4DOS (perhaps not for Windows), but later, 4NT.  There's also something called "Take Command".. i'm not sure the difference between 4NT and "Take Command".  People might not use either anymore.. And even back then people hardly used them.

https://jpsoft.com/all-downloads/previous-versions.html

Comment: Oh we throwing in any 3rd party shell into the mix then, right?

Comment: I don't know, but since he mentioned others that are 3rd party, but objected to them for being linux based, I mentioned some 3rd party ones that aren't linux based.

Comment: True, I guess I only based that on the title and the first sentence and the word "native". Windows is starting to support Linux OSes and their shells natively though in the open source area they extend it onto their OS.

Answer (score 1):

Other shells exist for Windows.  For example, [Hamilton C Shell](https://hamiltonlabs.com/Cshell.htm).  It is native Win32 implementation of the UNIX C shell.  The creator, [Nicole Hamilton](https://hamiltonlabs.com/NicoleHamilton/), is a former Microsoft employee and SuperUser [member](https://superuser.com/users/156601/nicole-hamilton).

Comment: never liked Cshell or Kshell. always drove me crazy. good find!

Comment: It's clear from his question that he wasn't asking about linux style shells.

Comment: @barlop Interesting, I dont see that statement as being true in the slightest.

Answer (score 0):

There are, maybe haven't gotten enough publicity?

There is another Bash shell for Windows, from a direct W32 port.  No, not WSL, not VMs, no not Cygwin.   It even handles drive letters.  I used this a lot in a VM on a shared drive where other solutions refused to work.  It's kind of old, maybe why it was forgotten:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/win-bash/

### Yori Shell

However, I really recommend the Yori shell (named after the Tron character I think):

- http://www.malsmith.net/yori/
- https://github.com/malxau/yori

Powershell is just too weird for casual use.  But maybe you dabble in Windows and just want a shell that works like the DOS/NT-cmd shell did but has been improved this century?  Maybe has some features Unix had by the 80s?  Maybe ANSI colors?  Command substitution and multitasking?  Harkens back to 4NT?

Yori is that.  The developer is responsive as well.